# Is it possible to allow for a script in a CI/CD job to fail?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

**Entire** jobs [can be allowed to fail](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure)

```
job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - execute_script_that_will_fail
  allow_failure: true
```

**Is it possible to have, in a series of scripts, one that is allowed to fail (and others - not)?**

```
job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - execute_script_that_MAY_fail_and_should_be_marked_somehow_in_this_config_as_such
    - execute_script_that_MUST_NOT_fail
```

The rationale is that there may be scripts which are related, should be grouped together and sequential, and only some of them are allowed to fail.

An example could be a docker deployment with a `build` (must not fail), a `stop` of a container (which may fail if the container is not running) and a `run` (which must not fail).

My current workaround is to split this into separate jobs but this is an ugly hack:

```
stages:
  - one
  - two
  - three

one:
  stage: one
  script:
    - execute_script_that_MUST_NOT_fail

two:
  stage: two
  script:
    - execute_script_that_MAY_fail
  allow_failure: true

three:
  stage: three
  script:
    - execute_script_that_MUST_NOT_fail
```

Comment: Use BASH syntax for this instead. For just a single command/script that is allowed to fail, we could print that it failed but continue by using the bash OR (double pipes).

`my_script || echo "My script failed ($?)"`

Comment: I had a similar question.  I wanted to ignore any error in a `logging` step: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67131467/ci-pipeline-ignore-any-commands-that-fail-in-a-given-step

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A job fails if any of the script steps inside it return a failed status. So you need to prevent that from happening, and the simplest way is to add `|| true` to the step (or some logging like @ahogen suggests in a comment):

```
job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - execute_script_that_MAY_fail || true
    - execute_script_that_MUST_NOT_fail
```