# CI-pipeline ignore any commands that fail in a given step

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm trying to debug a CI pipeline and want to create a custom `logger` stage that dumps a bunch of information about the environment in which the pipeline is running.

I tried adding this:

```
stages:
    - logger

logger-commands:
    stage: logger
    allow_failure: true
    script:
        - echo 'Examining environment'
        - echo PWD=$(pwd) Using image ${CI_JOB_IMAGE}
        - git --version
        - echo --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        - env
        - echo --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        - npm --version
        - node --version
        - echo java -version
        - mvn --version
        - kanico --version
        - echo --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The problem is that the Java command is failing because `java` isn't installed.  The error says:

```
/bin/sh: eval: line 217: java: not found
```

I know I could remove the line `java -version`, but I'm trying to come up with a canned logger that I could use in all my CI-Pipelines, so it would include: Java, Maven, Node, npm, python, and whatever else I want to include and I realize that some of those commands will fail because some of the commands are not found.

Searching for the above solution got me close.

- [GitLab CI: How to continue job even when script fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59180675/gitlab-ci-how-to-continue-job-even-when-script-fails) - Which did help.   By adding `allow_failure: true` I found that even if the logger job failed the remaining stages would run (which is desirable).  The answer also suggests a syntax to wrap commands in which is:

```
./script_that_fails.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 || FAILED=true

if [ $FAILED ]
    then ./do_something.sh
fi
```

So that is helpful, but my question is this.

**Is there anything built into gitlab's CI-pipeline syntax (or bash syntax) that allows all commands in a given step to run even if one command fails?**

- [Is it possible to allow for a script in a CI/CD job to fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55708975/is-it-possible-to-allow-for-a-script-in-a-ci-cd-job-to-fail) - suggests adding the UNIX bash OR syntax as shown below:

```
        - npm --version || echo nmp failed
        - node --version  || echo node failed
        - echo java -version || echo java failed
```

That is a little cleaner (syntax) but I'm trying to make it simpler.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to allow for a script in a CI/CD job to fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55708975/is-it-possible-to-allow-for-a-script-in-a-ci-cd-job-to-fail)

Comment: GitLab CI relies entirely on the return code of the executed command. The only workaround is to make the command return a successful status - in your case, probably something like this: `echo java -version || echo "No java installed"`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answers already mentioned are good, but I was looking for something simpler so I wrote the following bash script. The script always returns a zero exit code so the CI-pipeline always thinks the command was successful.

If the command did fail, the command is printed along with the non-zero exit code.

```
# File: runit

#!/bin/sh
"$@"
EXITCODE=$?
if [ $EXITCODE -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "CMD: $@"
    echo "Ignored exit code ($EXITCODE)"
fi
exit 0
```

Testing it as follows:

```
./runit ls "/bad dir"
echo "ExitCode = $?"
```

Gives this output:

```
ls: cannot access /bad dir: No such file or directory
CMD: ls /bad dir
Ignored exit code (2)
ExitCode=0
```

Notice even though the command failed the `ExitCode=0` shows what the ci-pipeline will see.

To use it in the pipeline, I have to have that shell script available.  I'll research how to **include** it, but it must be in the CI runner job.   For example,

```
stages:
  - logger-safe

logger-safe-commands:
  stage: logger-safe
  allow_failure: true
  script:
    - ./runit npm --version
    - ./runit java -version
    - ./runit mvn --version
```

I don't like this solution because it requires extra file in the repo but this is in the spirit of what I'm looking for.  So far the simplest  **built in** solution is:

```
    - some_command || echo command failed $?
```